# Not Able to show UIAlert on Exception

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, exception

I am using UITableView. And if there is no network connection then there will be exception thrown in viewDidload. My viewDidLoad function is:

```
 @try {
                NSLog(@"Request URL = %@",URLString);

                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                                  URLWithString:URLString]];
                NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                     returningResponse:nil error:nil];

                NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
                NSDictionary *tableData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:&jsonParsingError];
                // Grab whole data with data field in JSON
                //    responseArray = [tableData objectForKey:@"data"];


                responseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[tableData objectForKey:@"data"]];
                for(int i = 0; i < responseArray.count; i++)
                {
                    NSArray * tempArray = responseArray[i];
                    responseArray[i] = [tempArray mutableCopy];
                }


                UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(280.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sort_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(showActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                UIBarButtonItem *barbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barbutton;

        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            exceptionOccured = YES;
            NSLog(@"Exception Ocurred");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error in connectivity" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I am doing this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    @try {

    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    tempDict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in CEll Create");
        NSLog(@"Draw Alert");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error in connectivity" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

and in AlertViewDelegate Function I am doing

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now problem is that it is not showing the Alert whenever there is an exception and re-throws the exception and shows the Error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x2)
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You should rewrite your code to avoid throwing exceptions. They are not intended to be used for normal conditions like network connections being unavailable.

Comment: Just because you catch an exception doesn't mean it automatically disappears. You're just offered a chance to clean the situation and reset your data to a "stable" state. Here you're just showing an alert and taking no further action to correct the problem, so the exception still goes down and raises.

Comment: @Cyrille So what should I do to stop it creating the more cells??

Comment: When you're reaching `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's already too late. The table view already wants this many rows, when in fact you have less. As said by everyone else, exceptions are 1) not a magic solution for this, 2) not intended to be used like that

Comment: I want just add to this that in case of assertion, like returnig nil in 'cellForRow' try/catch won't prevent an application crash, you should prevent exceptions and use try/catch in those cases that an anexpected behaviour could happen, like working with files an I/O exception could be rised

Comment: Exceptions when developing for iOS/Mac OSX should be reserved for programmer errors **only**. If the frameworks throw an exception, you typically want to crash. Instead, you should validate method parameters and return values, and use a different form of error reporting (NSError, Delegation etc…). Using exceptions as an error handling mechanism in production code causes performance issues, and can cause very bad memory issues as ARC does not handle exceptions well. This isn't Java.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid throwing exceptions in your code.

First of all you could use [Reachability Class](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) to determine whether or not an active internet connection is available.

I would definitively recommend using the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol for URL connections. So you can use the better asynchronous programming style.

Comment: Reachability should only be used *after* an error has occurred loading something to find out why for appropriate error messages, or for automatic-refresh behavior. If you want to know if you can load something, try to load it and handle the error. (Reachability doesn't guarantee success when online or failure when offline, so there's no point in asking it before you load something.)

Comment: No guarantee, right. But actually Reachability is extremely fast and accurate. You can rely on it without problems. For almost every application Reachability will be good enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, I completely disagree with your assessment that you can rely on it without problems. For example, if your server is returning HTTP 500 errors, Reachability will report you're OK but you will get an error when loading data. You have to handle errors, not try to avoid them with Reachability. Similarly, it's easy for Reachability to report "no connection" but a URL load would work fine; for example, if the content is already locally cached.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else. When `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called it means the system needs the tableView to be reloaded. Therefore, you should not check for data inside that function. When you enter this function, you should be sure that your data is ok.

What you have to do is firstly check your data in a specific function:

```
     -(void)CheckData(NSArray *responseArray) {
            @try {
                //Retrieve your data & check if its valid
                self.dataArray = responseArray;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error in check Data");
                NSLog(@"Draw Alert");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error     in connectivity" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
```

Then, implement your data source delegates:

```
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
           return [self.dataArray count];
       }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease] ; 
        }

        //TODO: Init your cell using your self.dataArray content

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend import this `SystemConfiguration` framework and use the same. This will check whether network connection is available or not. Below is the simple code:-

```
    #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
-(void)yourMethod
{    
     SCNetworkConnectionFlags flags = 0;
            if (yourhostname && [yourhostname length] > 0)
            {
                flags = 0;
                BOOL found = NO;
                SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, [yourhostname UTF8String]);
                if (reachabilityRef)
                {
                    found = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags)
                    &&  (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)
                    && !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
                    CFRelease(reachabilityRef);
                    reachabilityRef = NULL;
                }
                if (found)
                {       
                   NSLog(@"Connection available");         
                  }
                  else
                 {
                  NSLog(@"Connection not available");         
                  }
}
```

Comment: @ hussain Shabbir: What is pingHost here?

Comment: Sorry it was typo mistake please check i have modified

Comment: @ hussain Shabbir:Will that work on Simulator too?? because I am getting Connection not available every time?

Comment: Basically connection here means your VPN connection. If it is not connected to vpn then definetely it will show connection not available

Comment: @ hussain Shabbir: Is there any way to know about the normal wifi or mobile internet connection

Comment: Well this framework is meant to be system host. It will only check the server which your application is connected. For internet or wifi iam not sure sorry:(

Comment: See my comment on the other answer; you need to handle loading errors, not try to avoid them by using reachability.